# Mahler Volume of the Snub 24-Cell

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have been working recently on the Mahler conjecture and I am interested in what the Mahler volume of the snub 24-cell in order to check an example calculation.

The recent paper regarding the snub 24-cell (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.3433v2.pdf) doesn't mention the volume of the dual of the snub 24-cell, which is what I am interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a comment embellished with an image. It seems that the paper you cite,
in its earlier arXiv version,

> Mehmet Koca, Mudhahir Al-Ajmi, Nazife Ozdes Koca.
>   "Quaternionic Representation of Snub 24-Cell and its Dual Polytope Derived From $E_8$ Root System." ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2109))

describes the structure of the dual of the snub $24$-cell in sufficient
explicit metrical detail 
("The dual polytope of the snub 24-cell is explicitly constructed")
to enable the volume to be computed...?
("We have $96$ cells of the same type constituting the dual snub-$24$ cell.")
Not that it would be an easy calculation, but ...
And as you know, with that volume you can then compute the Mahler volume.

---

[image: Figs.4+5]

Comment: This is very helpful, I'll add an answer with my calculation in case anyone else is ever interested. I didn't notice this figure in the older version of the paper!